# How to expire refresh token after 15 minutes on grails spring security rest application

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

We are working in a Grails 3.2.12 project using Spring Security Core(3.0.0) and Spring Security  Rest plugin(2.0.0.M2) for user authorization and access control.

Now, we need to implement a way to expire the user access after 15 minutes of inactive in the system.

The project is configured to expire the access token 15 minutes after login and the refresh token process is inactive, so, the user need to login again.

The problem is that refresh token never expire by default, and if we implement the refresh token process, the user access never expire.

What is the solution that we planned: We will change the expiration time  of access token for 5 minutes, and create an expiration time for the refresh token for 15 minutes.

There are any way to create an expiration time for the refresh token on  grails spring security rest plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Funny I just gave some advice about this question on Slack:
From looking at the code you would have to override the functionality of these three classes, at the minimum:

https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/blob/ffa848c9c6dd82f92f2ab489cb5d7a1515c587f2/spring-security-rest/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/RestOauthController.groovy#L137

https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/blob/develop/spring-security-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/storage/jwt/JwtTokenStorageService.groovy#L52

https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/blob/ffa848c9c6dd82f92f2ab489cb5d7a1515c587f2/spring-security-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/token/generation/jwt/AbstractJwtTokenGenerator.groovy#L113

It seems like the way it differentiates between a refresh token is by it not having an expiration, so you would have to come up with an alternative mechanism. Good luck...

Comment: Thanks @virtualdogbert. I think that you adviced my team colleague. 
We are thinkin to override the Refresh Token generator to add an expire date, and override the validator to check if the RefreshToken is valid.

When we finish this task, i will post the results.